# Bridging LAN networks privately in office environment

Tags: routing, switch, ethernet, lan, bridge

I've begun looking into network bridging, must most of it is witchcraft for me so far. I currently have the following setup:

[image: Basic overview of current network]

I use PC 1 as my development station and PC 2 as a deployment/test station. I'd like to be able to create socket connections from PC 1 to the secondary network of devices represented by the lower LAN (where the switch is) and interfaced through NIC 2. However, I do not want these devices (robots, controllers, etc) to be exposed to the full office network and especially the active internet connection. Both PCs run a mixture of Windows and Ubuntu VMs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look like you confuse about network bridging and subnetting. What you want to achive is subnetting and to enforce rules you could done it with acl or firewall as other said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bridging means that you are placing the bridged devices onto the same network.

A common method for what you are trying to achieve is to use a firewall and place the things you don't want to get to your office network on the outside interface of the firewall. Your office network can then get to the devices, but the devices cannot get to the office network.

Comment: Yes, simple bridging is essentially combining both LANs. The problem with the firewall method is that I only want my PC 1 to find the devices, not the whole office network (which I do not have control over).

Comment: That can be handled by the firewall rules. My company does this sort of thing all the time. You are basically setting up a restricted lab.

Comment: So convince IT?

Comment: How you handle configuring the network should be up to you, the network professional. Company politics are outside the scope of what we can answer for you. You can deal with this using a firewall or something like ACLs on a router, and we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could either bridge your connections (NICs) at PC2 or write a static route on command line to get 2 networks talk to each oher. If your switch is manageable you could also write an ACL not to allow outbound connections towards PC1 network.

Just thinking also, if you removed the default gateway from the nodes on your lower network tthey can stay isolates, am I wrong?

Regards...

Comment: I'm curious about the static route method. I'll look it up myself, but do you have any suggested sources in the meantime? I also would like the ability to have two-way communication between my PC 1 and the devices, so I'd need those outbound connections (but not towards the "internet"/office). Without the default gateway I've had problems in the past where I couldn't even ping from PC 2.